# controlling of push and pop methods in linked list implementation

Tags: java, linked-list

I was reading about tree implementation in java language by using eclipse ...
I found push and pop methods need to be implemented ... Here are the two methods implemented by my teacher :

```
public class LimitedStack<E> {
    private Node<E> first; // refererar till första elementet i listan
    private Node<E> last; // refererar till sista elementet i listan
    private int size; // antal element i listan
    private int maxSize; // maximalt antal tillåtna element i listan

    public LimitedStack(int maxSize) {
        first = last = null;
        size = 0;
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
    }

    public void push(E x) {
        Node<E> n = new Node<E>(x);
        if (first == null) {//no overflow in this case
            first = n;
            size++;
        } else { // add new node to front
            n.next = first;
            first = n;
            if (size == maxSize) { //overflow, at least two elements
                Node<E> p = first;
                while (p.next.next != null) { //lookup second last
                    p = p.next;
                }
                p.next = null; //remove last from list
            } else { //no overflow, increase size
                size++;
            }
        }
    }

    public E pop() {
        if (size == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        E temp = first.element;
        first = first.next;
        size--;
        return temp;
    }
}
```

When I implemented those methods by myself I did like this :

```
public void push(E x) {
    if(first == null) {
        first = new Node<E>(x);
    } else if (size==maxSize) {
        Node<E> act = first;
        last =null;
        first = new Node<E>(x);
        first.next=act;
    } else {
        Node<E> act = first;
        first = new Node<E>(x);
        first.next=act;
    }
    size++;
}


public E pop() {
    if(size == 0) {
        return null;
    } else {
        Node<E> act = first;
        first = act.next;
       return act.element;
       size--;
    }
}
```

Is my implementation correct if we compare it with my teacher's answer ?

Thanks

Comment: This is a linked list based bounded stack, nothing common with tree.

Comment: to check whether is works correctly, create several unit tests reflecting different usage scenarios, and compare what is done to what is expected to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not correct.

In `push()` you split it into 3 condition.

1. The linked list is empty
2. The linked list is full
3. The linked list neither empty nor full

Your code will failed at second condition. When the linked list is full, according to your teacher's answer, you should **push new element into the list**, **remove last element in list** and **the size of the linked list is unmodified**.

In your code, you didn't remove the last element. You set last to null **but you never set last to correct value instead of null**. And the `size` of the linked list is still increased because you put your `size++` outside of the `if else`.

So your code of `push()` should like this:

```
public void push(E x) {
    Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(x);
    if(first == null) {
        first = newNode;
        size++;
    } else if (size==maxSize) {
        Node<E> act = first;
        // last =null;
        first = newNode;
        first.next=act;
    } else {
        Node<E> act = first;
        first = newNode;
        first.next=act;
        size++;
    }
}
```

And your `pop()` function. You can actually see that your code is very similar to teacher's. However, you need to put `size--;` before your `return act.element;`, because when the method executes `return` statement, it **mostly** will exit method and return to the caller, at least in your code.

---

As @SashaSalauyou says, this is not a tree, it just a linked list right now, and you should at least write some `test codes` to your `push()` and `pop()` to see if your linked list is correct or not. For example, you can try to push some values and pop some values in your `main` and use debugger to check the linked list is working correctly or not.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not correct. You decrease size after return statement in pop function.

Comment: is that only the wrong thing ? thanks